# How do I change the machine name of a field once it's been created

Tags: entities, database, nodes

I spaced out while typing the field name an now the machine name is not what I wanted it to be. I know it's just an annoyance. but I'm wondering if there is some way to alter the machine name of a field once it is created.

I suppose this leads me into the second part of my question. if I created a field, and it is no longer being used, how do I go about deleting it, does this have to be done from the database, or can it be done somewhere in the UI.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short, you can't change the machine name. In theory, it's obviously possible, but it will require quite a bit of messing with the database. If you've only just created the field, it's far easier to remove it and create a new one.

The basics would be to rename all entries on `field_config` and `field_config_instance`, but as soon as you start using the field, the machine names get's stored in a hundred different places. *Views* config, *Panels* config, *Features* and more, and by then, changing it is *not* fun.

Deleting fields can be done on: `admin/structure/types/manage/[machine_name_of_content_type]/fields`, which you can reach through the "*Manage fields*" tab on any content type.

Comment: But don't the fields still remain in the database, for instance, I created a new field with the popper name, however when I go to add a new field to a content type, the old field name still appears as an option ... perhaps I'm not understanding exactly how fields work.

Comment: There is a functionality that I haven't investigated a lot, that deletes fields and their content over time. The reason is to prevent that a site grinds to a halt when deleting a fields with thousands of entries. If the field is not used anywhere, I would expect it to go away on the next cron run.

Comment: I tried to do a sed -i -e s/old_field/new_field/ on a site code and database dump. Unfortunately, something went wrong and after the dump restoration site was malfunctioning. Any ideas how to do it right way?

Comment: @Dmitry Vyal: The field name is stored in a few places in a serialized array – replacing one string with another string of a different length would break the unserialize() of the array and probably break the next bootstrap or Drupal.

Comment: @Charlie S: Thanks, will take care of it in the future.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. Although Drupal seems to store references to certain fields in multiple places, the biggest catch seems to be the serialized data storage in the field_config table in the data column. If you replace each instance of the old field name with the new field name, you must remember to recalculate the length of the new string and replace the character count the precedes each reference. For instance, something like: s:29:"field_revision_field_category" would become s:33:"field_revision_field_new_category" because I added 4 characters to the name. Hope this helps.

Comment: Author is correct in that you can't change the machine name easily.  However, deleting the field WILL NOT help. The machine name is retained even after deleting the field. I think that if the entire content type is whacked, you can start over. That is not a great solution in most cases, especially if there is already content that you don't want blown away

Answer (score 17):

My procedure is to use drush to clone the field first, then copy the field data with DB queries into the new field table. After I verify the contents of the cloned field, I delete the original field.

I do it this ways because I think the drush method of cloning fields will always be at least as reliable as any cloning code I might craft myself, the data copy query is pretty simple, and I get to check the new field before deleting the original.

1. `drush field-clone field_my_field field_my_field_clone`
2. Insert rows into `field_my_field_clone`, e.g., `INSERT field_my_field_clone SELECT * FROM field_my_field;`
3. Verify the contents of `field_my_field_clone`.
4. Delete the field using the UI, e.g., `admin/structure/types/manage/my-content-type/fields`

Comment: This is great!  For D7: 

INSERT field_data_field_my_field_clone SELECT * FROM field_data_field_my_field;
INSERT field_revision_field_my_field_clone SELECT * FROM field_revision_field_my_field;

Comment: I didn't know there was a "drush field-clone" command ! Awesome :)

Comment: What about views, panels, etc?  Manual fixes?

Comment: if you are using drush you can direclty delete the field with  `drush field-delete xxx` and you could also like `drush sql-query` as suggested by neubreed. @zkent, you will have te relink the new field in the existing views, panels, etc.

Comment: It looks like `field-clone` was dropped in Drush 9. Drupal developers that use 8.4+ will not be able to use this feature.

Answer (score 10):

In Drupal 7, you can use the [Field Rename](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_rename) module. 
In Drupal 6, you can use [CCK field rename](http://drupal.org/project/cck_field_rename) module.

Comment: There is now a Drupal 7 Version of this module at https://www.drupal.org/project/field_rename

Comment: It works. Just remember to keep the name length under the maximum.

Comment: any D8 project ?

Answer (score 6):

I have written an update script, which actually creates a new field and instance with the new machine name, copies all the old field data to the new one and lastly deletes the old instance.

```
// Set variables
$old_name = 'field_old_name';
$new_name = 'field_new_name';
$entity_type = 'node';
$bundle = 'page';

// Get old field info
$old_field = field_info_field($old_name);

// Create new field
$new_field = $old_field;
$new_field['field_name'] = $new_name;

if (!field_info_field($new_name)) {
  field_create_field($new_field);
}
else {
  field_update_field($new_field);
}

// Get old field instance
$old_instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $old_name, $bundle);
$new_instance = $old_instance;
$new_instance['field_name'] = $new_name;

if (!field_info_instance($entity_type, $new_name, $bundle)) {
  field_create_instance($new_instance);
}
else {
  field_update_instance($new_instance);
}

// Migrate old fields' data to the new ones
$field_data = db_select('field_data_' . $old_name, 'old')
  ->fields('old')
  ->condition('entity_type', $entity_type)
  ->condition('bundle', $bundle)
  ->execute();

while ($data = $field_data->fetchAssoc()) {
  $data_new = array();
  foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
    $column = str_replace($old_name, $new_name, $column);
    $data_new[$column] = $value;
  }
  db_insert('field_data_' . $new_name)
    ->fields($data_new)
    ->execute();
}

// Migrate old fields' revision data to the new ones
$field_revision = db_select('field_revision_' . $old_name, 'old')
  ->fields('old')
  ->condition('entity_type', $entity_type)
  ->condition('bundle', $bundle)
  ->execute();

while ($revision = $field_revision->fetchAssoc()) {
  $revision_new = array();
  foreach ($revision as $column => $value) {
    $column = str_replace($old_name, $new_name, $column);
    $revision_new[$column] = $value;
  }
  db_insert('field_revision_' . $new_name)
    ->fields($revision_new)
    ->execute();
}

// Delete old instance
field_delete_instance($old_instance);

// Purge fields
field_purge_batch(1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had to do this, and found it to not be too difficult, but my site is fairly simple.

Try this:

1. Create a new field with the proper name.
2. Run these queries in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO field_data_[NEW MACHINE NAME] (entity_type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id, language, delta, field_fabric_color_pattern_tid) SELECT cf.* FROM  `field_data_[OLD MACHINE NAME]` cf
```

```
INSERT INTO field_revision_[NEW MACHINE NAME] (entity_type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id, language, delta, field_fabric_color_pattern_tid) SELECT cf.* FROM  `field_revision_[OLD MACHINE NAME]` cf
```

(swap out [NEW MACHNIE NAME] and [OLD MACHINE NAME] with `field_your_field_names`)

3. Update any views involved to use the new field, and any other modules that point to that specific field (this is where things might get ugly if your site is complicated).  You can see any views that use your old field here: `/admin/reports/fields/views-fields`
4. Clear site cache

Comment: what for d8? is it working for paragraph too?

Answer (score 2):

// Change the field storage table names.
Here we are altering the name of the old table with new name.

```
db_rename_table($data_table_name, 'field_data_' . $new_field_name);
db_rename_table($revision_table_name, 'field_revision_' . $new_field_name);
```

// Change the field names in the field_config and field_instance_config tables.

```
db_update('field_config')
  ->fields(
    array(
      'field_name' => $new_field_name,
    )
  )
  ->condition('field_name', $field_name, '=')
  ->execute();

db_update('field_config_instance')
  ->fields(
    array(
      'field_name' => $new_field_name,
    )
  )
  ->condition('field_name', $field_name, '=')
  ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

With the drush field-clone answer above you can do the last MySQL step with Drush also (D7 example):

```
drush sql-query "INSERT field_data_field_my_field_clone SELECT * FROM field_data_field_my_field"

drush sql-query "INSERT field_revision_field_my_field_clone SELECT * FROM field_revision_field_my_field"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fiddle around in mysql you could try a [drush script](https://drupal.org/sandbox/pontusnilsson/1932784) I wrote called Field value copy.

You will need to setup your new field first and then call

```
drush fieldcopy OLDFIELDNAME NEWFIELDNAME
```

This will move existing data to the new field once done delete the old field.

Answer (score -1):

The [db_change_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_change_field/7) function may help you.

Answer (score -3):

Export the SQL file of your database, use the command line `sed` to replace all occurrences of the term to change, and re-import your database.

Comment: Downvoted your comment because this approach will wreak havoc on your Drupal installation since there are a few places in the database where the field names are PHP serialized. For more information about this, see the comments from @CharlieS (and others) under the accepted answer above.